# Magento Configurable Product Dynamic MSRP

Tags: product, configurable-product, msrp, dynamic-price

I have configurable products that have multiple attributes - like **size** and **color**.

Each simple product associated with that configurable product (size1 color1, size2 color1 etc.) has not only a **different price**, but a **different MSRP**. It was easy enough to get the price to change using the Magento admin, but it's not as easy with the MSRP.

How can I make the MSRP change for each combination of selected attributes?